# What do I need to change in order to sort from the 'population value'

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, linked-list

I'm currently working on a program that sorts a LinkedList. The data within the LinkedList are countries and their populations... the current structure of the list is [("Country", population), ("Country", population)] etc.

My code currently sorts it in order by country (A-Z).
What do I need to change on my code in order for it to sort it by population (largest to smallest)

```
# creating a linked list node.
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
```

```
# a function to traverse and print the linked list.
def printList(head):
    temp = head
    while temp:
        print(temp.data, end=" ")
        temp = temp.next
```

```
# a helper function that will set the currentNode at its correct position.
def sortLinkedListHelper(head, newNode):
    temp = Node()
    current = temp
    temp.next = head

    # checking the current node with each node of the linked list if it is smaller then, we are swapping.
    while current.next and current.next.data < newNode.data:
        current = current.next

    newNode.next = current.next
    current.next = newNode
    return temp.next
```

```
# a function that will sort the linked list.
def sortLinkedList(head):
    # a list to store the current result
    answerList = None
    current = head

    # current node will be pointing at the head of the linked list
    while current:
        """
        setting the nextNode pointer to the next node and calling the helper function that will set the current node at its correct position.
        """
        nextNode = current.next

        answerList = sortLinkedListHelper(answerList, current)
        current = nextNode
```

```
"""
finally returning the resultant sorted linked list making it the head node of the sorted linked list.
"""
return answerList
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # a list containing the data of the linked list.
    countries = [("Ukraine",41879904),("Brunei",442400),("Christmas Island (Australia)",1928),("Mauritius",1265985),("Lesotho",2007201),("Guatemala",16604026),("British Virgin Islands (UK)",30030),("Malta",493559)]

    # points to the head node of the linked list
    head = None

    # constructing the linked list from last to first
    for i in reversed(range(len(countries))):
        head = Node(countries[i], head)

    # printing the linked list before sorting
    print("Original Linked list: ")
    printList(head)

    # sorting the linked list.
    head = sortLinkedList(head)

    # print linked list
    print("\n\nSorted Linked list: ")
    printList(head)
```

I'm not massively experienced with coding - I only really have experience of up to GCSE level so the coding that I have there is a mixture of sources and my own research etc.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael suggests you want to access the second element of each tuple and use this one as the key for your sort.

```
# Example list of tuples:
countries = [("Ukraine",41879904),("Brunei",442400),("Christmas Island (Australia)",1928),("Mauritius",1265985),("Lesotho",2007201),("Guatemala",16604026),("British Virgin Islands (UK)",30030),("Malta",493559)]

# Function to access the second element:
def TulpleKey(tup):
    return tup[1]

# non mutating descending sort by key:
sorted(countries,key=TulpleKey,reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
[('Ukraine', 41879904), ('Guatemala', 16604026), ('Lesotho', 2007201), ('Mauritius', 1265985), ('Malta', 493559), ('Brunei', 442400), ('British Virgin Islands (UK)', 30030), ('Christmas Island (Australia)', 1928)]
```